Create a phone-book using LaTeX
I'm trying to create a phonebook using LaTeX that looks like this (below). I created the following using Notion.

The LaTeX code that I'm trying to modify for my purpose is:
\documentclass[dvipsnames,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering\sf
\rowcolors{2}{Green!10}{Yellow!10}
\begin{longtable}{*{4}{>{\scriptsize}c}}
\rowcolor{Gray!20}
\raisebox{-0.5pt}{\textbf{Employee Name}} & \raisebox{-0.5pt}{\textbf{Location}} & \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\Large\Telefon} & \raisebox{-0.5pt}{\textbf{Remarks}} \\
Tim Timmy     & Long Address  & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
Bim Bimmy     & Long Address  & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
Kim Kimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
Fim Fimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
Rim Rimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
Qim Qimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


How do I modify the code to introduce the following changes?

"Department of [dept.]" before each table.
Wrapping the text in each table entry. With the current piece of code, one can't write a lengthy remark or location.
Adding bullets inside remarks. I discovered that begin{itemize}..\end{itemize} does not work inside.


Both, bullets as well as wrapping is possible when you use p{} as column type. I am not 100% sure what you mean with question 1., but the rest works rather simple:
    \documentclass[dvipsnames,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a6paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{longtable,array}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newcommand{\entry}[4]{#1&#2&#3&#4}
    
    \begin{document}
    \centering\sffamily % use of \sf is deprecated
    \rowcolors{2}{Green!10}{Yellow!10}
{\bfseries--- Department of Ecology ---}
    \begin{longtable}{*{2}{>{\scriptsize}c>{\scriptsize}p{2cm}}}
    \rowcolor{Gray!20}
    \textbf{Employee Name} & \textbf{Location} & \Large\Telefon & \textbf{Remarks} \\
    Tim Timmy     & Long Address  & 01234567 & Long task X assigned \\ 
    Bim Bimmy     & Super Ultra Long Address  & 01234567 & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item test
        \item test
        \item test
    \end{itemize} \\ 
    Kim Kimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
    Fim Fimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
    Rim Rimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
    Qim Qimmy     &               & 01234567 & Task X assigned \\ 
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}

This yields the following:


Perfect. Contains everything I needed. Thank you so, so much Mr./Dr. Arne.

Could you please explain me the \begin{longtable}{*{2}{>{\scriptsize}c>{\scriptsize}p{2cm}}} part? I can't modify it properly to add more columns.

*{2}{>{\scriptsize}c>{\scriptsize}p{2cm}} means that you have 2 occurrences of the columns of type *>{\scriptsize}c>{\scriptsize}p{2cm}, that is, a centred c column and one that is a paragraph of length 2cm p{2cm}. In both the fonsize \scriptsize is applied.
